# Which is the noncentral multivariate t distribuiton

Tags: t-distribution, multivariate-distribution, non-central

In various documentations, I found out two definitions of the multivariate noncentral student $t$ distribution.

The most commonly density (PDF) found is (e.g., [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_t-distribution)):

$$\mathcal{T}(x;\mu, \sigma^2, \Sigma, \nu) = \frac{\Gamma((\nu+P)/2)}{(\pi \nu)^{P/2} \vert \sigma^2 \Sigma \vert^{1/2} \Gamma(\nu/2)}
\Bigg(1+\frac{(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu)}{\sigma^2 \nu}  \Bigg)^{-(v+P)/2}
 $$

where $\mu$ is the population mean, a $P$-dimensional vector, $\nu$ is the degrees of freedom of the variance estimate, $\sigma^2$ is the population variance, $\Sigma$ is the $P\times P$ *correlation* matrix, and finally, $x$ is one observed $t$ statistics, that is, a *studentized* vector (i.e., divided by the sample standard deviations).

However, I also found another defintion of this distribution in Kshirsagar, 1961 [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/CD5F06D1A1B030BB22232B61A345F4B2/S0305004100034885a.pdf/some-extensions-of-the-multivariate-t-distribution-and-the-multivariate-generalization-of-the-distribution-of-the-regression-coefficient.pdf?casa_token=YUpeXwx7yqkAAAAA:U0iMaj9X6q0qYtqa527hDiDxT8XIg3XDcLoho9ynxsX6o6sAXiSQtV4cdhJcxsShcf-CZjzmKQ)

$$\mathcal{T}(x;\mu, \sigma^2, \sigma'^2, \Sigma, \nu) = 
\frac{(\sigma'/\sigma)^P Exp \left(-\frac{1}{2 \sigma^2} \mu^T\Sigma^{-1}\mu \right) }{(\pi f)^{P/2} \vert \Sigma \vert^{1/2} \Gamma(f/2)} 
  \times
\sum_{\alpha=0}^{\infty}
\frac
{(\sigma'/\sigma)^\alpha \; 2^{\alpha/2} \Big(x^T \Sigma^{-1} x \Big)^\alpha \Gamma((\nu+P+\alpha)/2)}
{\sigma ^\alpha f^{\alpha/2} \alpha! \left(1+\frac{\sigma'^2}{\sigma^2} \times \frac{x^T \Sigma^{-1} x}{f}
\right)^{(\nu+P+\alpha)/2}}
$$

This second definition uses $\sigma'$ as the variance estimate could be any $\chi^2$ variate with $f$ degrees of freedom which may over- or underestimate $\sigma$. However, replace the ratio $\sigma' / \sigma$ by one for the usual standard deviation estimator.

The two formulas are quite different (and the second much slower to compute). Further, they do not return the same values given the same paramters. Finally, I generated random data following a binormal distribution and divided each scores by their standard deviations and found that the second seems to be fitting more aptly the empirical distribution, e.g.,

[image: 3D histogram showing simulated studentized scores and the density from the second equation]

where the bars are the data frequency and the curved surface the predicted density.

My question is: which one is the correct equation? If the first is good, what parameters should be given so that it fits well binormal studentized variates (say, for the sake of the example, with $\mu = \{95, 105\}$, $\sigma = 15$, $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}1 & \rho \\ \rho & 1\end{pmatrix}$ in which $\rho = 0.25$ and a sample size $n =10000$).

Comment: Could it be that the first equation is actually the distribution when the true population means are known? So this would be a "translated" centrat t distribution?

Comment: It seems that the first distribution returns the distributions of zero-mean scores divided by some square root of a chi-square with $\nu$ df, then translated by $\mu$ ([this reference](https://doi.org/10.1080/02331880500031407) provides more cues).