# Distribution of $X'\Sigma^{-1}X$ for $X$ following a multivariate $t$ distribution

Tags: chi-squared-distribution, multivariate-distribution, quadratic-form, f-distribution, non-central

According to Golam Kibria & Joarder (2006, p.7) [available here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228613894_A_short_review_of_multivariate_t-distribution) and Kotz & Nadarajah (2004, p. 19) [visible in google](https://books.google.fr/books?id=dmxtU-TxTi4C&printsec=frontcover&hl=fr#v=onepage&q&f=false), the distribution of $X'\Sigma^{-1}X /p$, for a known correlation matrix $\Sigma$ when $X$ is a $p$-long vector of $\{X_i\}$ with (assuming uncorrelated items)

$$ X_i \sim t_{v, \mu, \sigma^2}$$

a student-t distribution with location $\mu$ and scale $\sigma^2$, follows a $F$ distribution with degrees of freedom $p$ and $v$ and noncentrality parameter $\lambda$ = $\mu'\Sigma^{-1}\mu /p$.

Here is a cut-and-paste of the whole section 3.5 of Golam Kibrian & Joarder (result presented with no proof):

[image: Section 3.5 from Golam Kibria and Joarder, 2006]

I can't replicate this result with simulations so looked at the maths, and found something different (see below). Which is correct? **Edit** Actually, both may be incorrect as neither fit the results from simulations... Where did I make an error?

---

Herein, the demonstration is restricted to the case where correlation is null and assuming a unique variance $\sigma^2$ for all items in $X$. Setting the correlation to zero in $\Sigma$, we find that $X'\Sigma^{-1}X/p$ equals $\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^p X_i^2/\sigma^2$. As

$$X_i \sim t_{v,\mu_i,\sigma^2}$$
implies
$$ X_i/\sigma \sim t_{v,\mu_i/\sigma,1} = \frac{\mathcal{N}(\mu_i/\sigma,1)}{\sqrt{\chi_v^2/v}}$$
Thus,
$$\frac{X_i^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \frac{\chi^2_1(\mu_i^2/\sigma^2)}{\chi^2_v/v}$$
and consequently,
$$\begin{split}
\frac{1}{p}\sum_{i=1}^p \frac{X_i^2}{\sigma^2} &\sim \frac{\chi^2_p\left(\sum \mu_i^2/\sigma^2\right)/p}{\chi^2_v/v} 
\\
&= F_{p,v}\left(\sum \mu_i^2/\sigma^2\right)=F_{p,v}(\mu'\Sigma^{-1}\mu)
\end{split}$$

The line before the last comes from the fact that the sum of independent $\chi^2$ is a $\chi^2$ with the sum of the df and the sum of the noncentrality parameters. The last line is from the definition of a $F$ distribution.

This derivation differs from Kibria & Joarder's result as the noncentrality parameter is not divided by $p$ when the data are. Can we expand this demonstration to the case where correlation is non-null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Suppose the random variable $\textbf{X}$ has a multivariate t-distribution with mean vector $\mu$, covariance matrix $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ and degrees of freedom $\nu$, then $\textbf{X}^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \textbf{X}/p$  has the $F$ distribution with
> $\nu$ and $p$ degrees of freedoms and non-centrality parameter $\mu^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \mu/p $

You can make this work when you  define the multivariate t-distribution as

$$\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{X} = \frac{\mathbf{Y}+\boldsymbol{\mu}}{\sqrt{Z/\nu}}\\
\\
\text{where} \qquad \textbf{Y} \sim N(0,\boldsymbol{\Sigma}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad Z \sim \chi^2_\nu
\end{array}$$

Note that this differs from

$$\mathbf{X} = \frac{\mathbf{Y}}{\sqrt{Z/\nu}} +\boldsymbol{\mu}\\$$

which is, I believe, the more standard from of the multivariate t-disribution.

---

The distribution of the product of only the numerator is $\chi^2$ disributed $$(\mathbf{Y}+\boldsymbol{\mu})^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{Y}+\boldsymbol{\mu}) \sim \chi^2_{p}(\text{ncp} = \boldsymbol{\mu}^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{\mu})$$

The distribution of product with the entire fraction $\mathbf{X}$ is distributed as

$$\begin{array}{c}\mathbf{X}^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \mathbf{X}/p = \frac{(\mathbf{Y}+\boldsymbol{\mu})^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{Y}+\boldsymbol{\mu})/p}{Z/\nu} \sim \frac{Z_1/p}{Z_2/\nu}\\
\\
\text{where} \qquad Z_1 \sim \chi^2_{p}(\text{ncp} = \boldsymbol{\mu}^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{\mu}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad Z_2 \sim \chi^2_\nu
\end{array}$$

This ratio of two $\chi^2$ distributed variables, $Z_1$ and $Z_2$ (where $Z_1$ may be a non-central $\chi^2$-distribution), divided by their degrees of freedom, $\frac{Z_1/p}{Z_2/\nu}$, is equivalent to a F-distributed variable.

Comment: Maybe they meant to express $$(\mathbf{X}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\prime \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} (\mathbf{X}-\boldsymbol{\mu})/p$$ which is F distributed (without non-centrality parameter) if you use the more typical form of the multivariate t-distribution.

Comment: Yes, this is good, Thank you very much! I specify that $Y$ is a $p$ vector, and $Z$ is a scalar. The mean of $X$ is $\mu$ and the variance of $X$ is $\frac{v}{v-2} \sigma$.

Comment: The most frustrating part when working with multivariate $t$ distributions is that there are so many definitions, each sustaining a different generating process, and that the authors generally poorly define what type they have in mind... See [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/567579/143790) if you wish to disambiguate them...